# How to calculate heritability from variance components?

Tags: variance, dataset

I have 6 locations, 3 replications, 7 blocks, and 49 entries in a full diallel experiment. I am trying to find out the heritability for each trait in each location separately. So, here I have used the following R code to calculate broad sense heritability from variance components:

```
# Code 

library(lme4)
library(Matrix)
a<-read.csv("sadore.csv", header = T, na.strings = "NA")
summary(a)
head(a)
str(a) 

a1=lmer(Yield~(1|Entry)+ (1|Rep)+(1|Rep:Block), data=a)
summary(a1)

#formula
h2= v(Entry)/v(Entry)+v(Rep)/3+v(Rep:Block)/21+ v(Error)/63
```

But after that, I got heritability which is super high and not reasonable. I know I am doing something wrong here. So, is there any wrong in my formula or code?

Comment: Can you print the output of `summary(a1)` as well as the value you calculated for `h2`?

Comment: Random effects:

 Groups    Name          Variance Std.Dev.
 Entry     (Intercept)      1.99551  1.4126  
 Rep:Block (Intercept)  0.08888  0.2981  
 Rep       (Intercept)      0.00000  0.0000  
 Residual                      0.46240  0.6800  
Number of obs: 147, groups:  Entry, 49; Rep:Block, 21; Rep, 3

Fixed effects:

            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  13.3431     0.2194   60.81 

this is the output and I have got  0.9942344 for h2 after calculation which seems suspicious. This I have calculated from raw data and there I presumed to have some outliers.

Comment: Please copy/paste as an edit into your question and use the code indentation to accept fixed width.